# ReportViewer: Print reports and allow users to edit report design

Tags: printing, reportviewer, rdlc

I've been "playing" with ReportViewer and I need to know how to do the following things:

- Print report without creating a ReportViewer. Why? I don't want to show it, just print. ReportViewer is too slow.
- Allow users to edit report design. The idea is to allow users to drag and drop TextBoxes to fit a pre-printed form. For example: to print invoices in a pre-printed form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN print a report without a report viewer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Also I have seen a post somewhere that creates a class that inherits from PrintDocument and you can pass the report into. It was in C# and I converted it to VB and it works fine.

Edit: Here is the post that detials the ReportPrintDocument class. Code linked on bottom of post
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works but I really don't think it's a very nice solution. Take a look at the references, even in a console project you have to import WindowsForms. And the report is being printed as an image. I think that Microsoft ReportViewer design is pretty bad. Thanks again.

Comment: Rendering it as an image is pretty standard. What else you render it as? You are just passing the data to the printer. When you print it it looks exactly how you would expect. The reference to windows forms is used when they are constructing their local report. In a more realistic scenario you would probably define the report somewhere else and pass it to the print function. The printing itself does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question: you can not print report without using reportViewer control. But you can print thre report from reportViewer control without actually showing the report. Here is similar question explaining how to do printing of report whout preview 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410099/rdlc-print-auto-generate/6464465#6464465) 
.For the second part of the question there are several ways to edit report desing. First is to use report designer in visual studio. Which is not good for users becaouse most user dont have VS or knowlege how to use it.Another way is to edit the xml of thr rdlc file by hand which is difficult to do even by programers. What i can suggest is using ReportBuilder. But this possible only if you use report server not reports in local mode.If thre is something not clear please ask.
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
First part: Microsoft design was not so good then. It has no sense that I have to you use a UI control to be able to print a report.
Second part: I agree, an end user is not going to edit the report using Visual Studio or manually editing a XML file. ReportBuilder is coupled to SQL Server. I tried a free tool called fyiReporting Designer for editing RDLC but it was pretty bad. I save the report and it broke it. 
I hope to find a way to solve this issue soon because reporting is a very importart function to users.
Best Regards,
Francisco